# How to append parameter using boost::bind?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind

I'm trying to append another parameter to a ROS subscriber callback function using boost::bind, but I can't figure what is wrong with my code:

This is the callback function signature:

```
void setDigitalOutputCallback(const std_msgs::Bool& cmd, int index);
```

in a usual ROS callback, there would be only the first (cmd) parameter).
Then I'm trying to set the callback using:

```
digitalOutputSub[i] = nh.subscribe(topicName, 1, boost::bind(setDigitalOutputCallback, _1, i));
```

Sample code:

```
#include "std_msgs/Bool.h"
#include "ros/ros.h"

void setDigitalOutputCallback(const std_msgs::Bool& cmd, int index) {

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "blaster_driver");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Subscriber digitalOutputSub;
    std::string topicName = "test";
    int i = 1;
    digitalOutputSub = nh.subscribe(topicName.c_str(), 1, boost::bind(setDigitalOutputCallback, _1, i));

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler is giving a lot of errors on that line, but I can't understand what is wrong there:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’: test.cpp:15:100: error: no matching function for call to ‘ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const char*, int, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(const std_msgs::Bool_<std::allocator<void> >&, int), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<int> > >)’   digitalOutputSub = nh.subscribe(topicName.c_str(), 1, boost::bind(setDigitalOutputCallback, _1, i));
                                                                                                    ^ In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from test.cpp:2: /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:401:14: note: candidate: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(M), T*, const ros::TransportHints&)    Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size, void(T::*fp)(M), T* obj,
              ^~~~~~~~~ /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:401:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed: test.cpp:15:100: note:   mismatched types ‘void (T::*)(M)’ and ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(const std_msgs::Bool_<std::allocator<void> >&, int), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<int> > >’   digitalOutputSub = nh.subscribe(topicName.c_str(), 1, boost::bind(setDigitalOutputCallback, _1, i));
                                                                                                    ^ In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from test.cpp:2: /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:412:14: note: candidate: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(M) const, T*, const ros::TransportHints&)    Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size, void(T::*fp)(M) const, T* obj,
              ^~~~~~~~~ /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:412:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed: test.cpp:15:100: note:   mismatched types ‘void (T::*)(M) const’ and ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(const std_msgs::Bool_<std::allocator<void> >&, int), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<int> > >’   digitalOutputSub = nh.subscribe(topicName.c_str(), 1, boost::bind(setDigitalOutputCallback, _1, i));
                                                                                                    ^ In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from test.cpp:2: /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:464:14: note: candidate: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const M>&), T*, const ros::TransportHints&)    Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size,
              ^~~~~~~~~ /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:464:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed: test.cpp:15:100: note:   mismatched types ‘void (T::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const M>&)’ and ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(const std_msgs::Bool_<std::allocator<void> >&, int), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<int> > >’   digitalOutputSub = nh.subscribe(topicName.c_str(), 1, boost::bind(setDigitalOutputCallback, _1, i));
                                                                                                    ^ In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from test.cpp:2: /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:474:14: note: candidate: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const M>&) const, T*, const ros::TransportHints&)    Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size,
              ^~~~~~~~~ /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:474:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed: test.cpp:15:100: note:   mismatched types ‘void (T::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const M>&) const’ and ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(const std_msgs::Bool_<std::allocator<void> >&, int), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<int> > >’   digitalOutputSub = nh.subscribe(topicName.c_str(), 1, boost::bind(setDigitalOutputCallback, _1, i));
                                                                                                    ^ In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from test.cpp:2: /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:528:14: note: candidate: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(M), const boost::shared_ptr<U>&, const ros::TransportHints&)    Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size, void(T::*fp)(M),
              ^~~~~~~~~ /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:528:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed: test.cpp:15:100: note:   mismatched types ‘void (T::*)(M)’ and ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(const std_msgs::Bool_<std::allocator<void> >&, int), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<int> > >’   digitalOutputSub = nh.subscribe(topicName.c_str(), 1, boost::bind(setDigitalOutputCallback, _1, i));
                                                                                                    ^ In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from test.cpp:2: /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:539:14: note: candidate: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(M) const, const boost::shared_ptr<U>&, const ros::TransportHints&)    Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size, void(T::*fp)(M) const,
              ^~~~~~~~~ /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:539:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed: test.cpp:15:100: note:   mismatched types ‘void (T::*)(M) const’ and ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(const std_msgs::Bool_<std::allocator<void> >&, int), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<int> > >’   digitalOutputSub = nh.subscribe(topicName.c_str(), 1, boost::bind(setDigitalOutputCallback, _1, i));
                                                                                                    ^ In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from test.cpp:2: /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:593:14: note: candidate: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const M>&), const boost::shared_ptr<U>&, const ros::TransportHints&)    Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size,
              ^~~~~~~~~ /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:593:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed: test.cpp:15:100: note:   mismatched types ‘void (T::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const M>&)’ and ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(const std_msgs::Bool_<std::allocator<void> >&, int), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<int> > >’   digitalOutputSub = nh.subscribe(topicName.c_str(), 1, boost::bind(setDigitalOutputCallback, _1, i));
                                                                                                    ^ In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from test.cpp:2: /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:604:14: note: candidate: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const M>&) const, const boost::shared_ptr<U>&, const ros::TransportHints&)    Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size,
              ^~~~~~~~~ /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:604:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed: test.cpp:15:100: note:   mismatched types ‘void (T::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const M>&) const’ and ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(const std_msgs::Bool_<std::allocator<void> >&, int), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<int> > >’   digitalOutputSub = nh.subscribe(topicName.c_str(), 1, boost::bind(setDigitalOutputCallback, _1, i));
                                                                                                    ^ In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from test.cpp:2: /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:655:14: note: candidate: template<class M> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (*)(M), const ros::TransportHints&)    Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size, void(*fp)(M), const TransportHints& transport_hints = TransportHints())
              ^~~~~~~~~ /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:655:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed: test.cpp:15:100: note:   mismatched types ‘void (*)(M)’ and ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(const std_msgs::Bool_<std::allocator<void> >&, int), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<int> > >’   digitalOutputSub = nh.subscribe(topicName.c_str(), 1, boost::bind(setDigitalOutputCallback, _1, i));
                                                                                                    ^ In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from test.cpp:2: /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:703:14: note: candidate: template<class M> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const M>&), const ros::TransportHints&)    Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size, void(*fp)(const boost::shared_ptr<M const>&), const TransportHints& transport_hints = TransportHints())
              ^~~~~~~~~ /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:703:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed: test.cpp:15:100: note:   mismatched types ‘void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const M>&)’ and ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(const std_msgs::Bool_<std::allocator<void> >&, int), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<int> > >’   digitalOutputSub = nh.subscribe(topicName.c_str(), 1, boost::bind(setDigitalOutputCallback, _1, i));
                                                                                                    ^ In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from test.cpp:2: /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:749:14: note: candidate: template<class M> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, const boost::function<void(const boost::shared_ptr<const M>&)>&, const VoidConstPtr&, const ros::TransportHints&)    Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size, const boost::function<void (const boost::shared_ptr<M const>&)>& callback,
              ^~~~~~~~~ /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:749:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed: test.cpp:15:100: note:   ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(const std_msgs::Bool_<std::allocator<void> >&, int), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<int> > >’ is not derived from ‘const boost::function<void(const boost::shared_ptr<const M>&)>’   digitalOutputSub = nh.subscribe(topicName.c_str(), 1, boost::bind(setDigitalOutputCallback, _1, i));
                                                                                                    ^ In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from test.cpp:2: /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:798:14: note: candidate: template<class M, class C> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, const boost::function<void(C)>&, const VoidConstPtr&, const ros::TransportHints&)    Subscriber subscribe(const std::string& topic, uint32_t queue_size, const boost::function<void (C)>& callback,
              ^~~~~~~~~ /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:798:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed: test.cpp:15:100: note:   ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(const std_msgs::Bool_<std::allocator<void> >&, int), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<int> > >’ is not derived from ‘const boost::function<void(C)>’   digitalOutputSub = nh.subscribe(topicName.c_str(), 1, boost::bind(setDigitalOutputCallback, _1, i));
                                                                                                    ^ In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from test.cpp:2: /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:835:14: note: candidate: ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(ros::SubscribeOptions&)    Subscriber subscribe(SubscribeOptions& ops);
              ^~~~~~~~~ /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:835:14: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. From this [page](http://docs.ros.org/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle.html) it looks like you're trying to call the third from last `subscribe` overload. Is your `bind` expression convertible to the `boost::function` parameter type of that overload?

Comment: I've never used bind before, but from what I got from https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html#bind.purpose, there are no requirements for the parameter types. Am I reading it wrong? "It supports arbitrary function objects, functions, function pointers, and member function pointers, and is able to bind any argument to a specific value or route input arguments into arbitrary positions. bind does not place any requirements on the function object; in particular, it does not need the result_type, first_argument_type and second_argument_type standard typedefs. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc, it seems you want to use following overload:

```
Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(
    const std::string & topic,
    uint32_t queue_size,
    const boost::function<void(C)> &    callback,
    const VoidConstPtr &    tracked_object = VoidConstPtr(),
    const TransportHints &  transport_hints = TransportHints() 
)
```

But you don't have correct matching, try to create your `boost::function` as variable:

```
boost::function<void (const std_msgs::Bool&)> f =
    boost::bind(setDigitalOutputCallback, _1, i);

digitalOutputSub = nh.subscribe(topicName.c_str(), 1, f);
```

Not sure if you don't have to specify template argument:

```
digitalOutputSub = nh.subscribe<std_msgs::Bool>(topicName.c_str(), 1, f);
```

Comment: That got it working. I had to specify the template argument for the subscribe call, as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I think passing `topicName` as `std::string` and may be `i` (second parameter of `subscribe`) as `unsigned` can help.